# TypeError: editorState.getCurrentContent is not a function

Tags: draftjs

I am trying to console the result from react draft wysiwyg and I am getting editorState.getCurrentContent is not a function. I am not sure where did I go wrong. Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import {EditorState} from "draft-js";
import { stateToHTML } from "draft-js-export-html";
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';

const AddBlog= () => {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
        () => EditorState.createEmpty(),
      );

    const handleChange = (editorState) =>{
        const contentState = stateToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent())
        // JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
        console.log(contentState)
       }


    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="card-wrapper-tutorial">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                <h4 className="card-title">New Code Snippet</h4>
                    <form autoComplete="off">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                            <input id="title" type="text" className="form-control"  placeholder="title" name="title"  disabled = {disabled}  onChange={handleChange}  />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="body">Body</label>
                            <Editor  
                                defaultEditorState={editorState}
                                onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
                                wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
                                editorClassName="editor-class"
                                toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                        </div>
                       <div className="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                        {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}
                        &nbsp;Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default AddBlog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `handleChange` in two places which they don't belong

1. on the input's `onChange`, the callback for `onChange` would not
   be an `editorState` but and input event [e](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange).
2. on the `Editor`
   component, the callback for `onChange` would not be an `editorState`
   also but a `RawDraftContentState` which is the string html.

You probably meant to place it in the onEditorStateChange for `Editor`:

```
      <Editor
        defaultEditorState={editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={editorState => {
          setEditorState(editorState);
          handleChange(editorState);
        }}
        wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
        editorClassName="editor-class"
        toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
      />
```

or leaving the code as is and modifying the `handleChange` to expect `RawDraftContentState`

```
    const handleChange = (rawDraftContentState) =>{
        // no need for convertToRaw or stateToHtml anymore
        console.log(rawDraftContentState)
    }
```